# Postgres plpgsql procedure: counter of events

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

I am writing a procedure which has the following data:

- Page id
- Event (what user made for example went to analytic page or close window etc
- Created (datetime of event)
- User id

So the procedure have to be written on plpgsql language and has to do
the following steps:
1.Order data by created

2. Set page_closed_without_activity counter to 0 (on each page_id)
3. Select users who worked with the page and find the event data.event == "entrance_to_page"
4. If immediately after that event the user performed one of the events - out_analytics || out_analytic_page || out_from_analytics → increase page_closed_without_activity counter by 1
5. Go to next event data.event == "entrance_to_page". One particular user can increase counter many times if after event "entrance_to_page" there is  one of events  out_analytics || out_analytic_page || out_from_analytics. The meaning of this is that user come on page of analytic and doesnt know what to do and he goes out

So my question is what architecture of procedure should i choose?
I thought maybe i should use cycle FOR columns:

page_id
user_id
event
created
counter

But how to write that if previous record page_id and user_id the same
as following and previous event = "entrance_to_page" and the current is
out_analytics || out_analytic_page || out_from_analytics thats why the is counter:=counter+1

And then if page_id changed then counter starts from 0 and the cycle repeats

I'm new at writing procedure  so could you help
with best practises fo such cases?

Comment: Pls, add sample data and desired result.

Comment: Why does this have to be done with PL/pgSQL? The described results can be achieved with SQL without resorting to procedural programming.

Comment: this will be a procedure with lot of action, simple this part of code I have not manage to make yet

Answer (score 0):

You were wright. That was easily made using LEAD function.
I haven't got data yet, cause it will be available next sprint)
but I think code something like that will succeed:

```
SELECT
object_id,
event,
fdm.page_id as page,
event,
LEAD(event,1) OVER (
        PARTITION BY page_id,object_id, 
        ORDER BY created
    ) as event_lead
FROM user_activity as ua

select
page,
created,
count(*) FILTER (WHERE event = 'entrance_to_page' 
                and event_lead in ( 'out_analytics_to_isu', 
                                    'out_analytic_page', 
                                    'out_isu_from_analytics') AS page_lazy_view
from temp_lazy_view as tlv
group by page_id, tlv.created::date
```